# Custom headers in angular2 request

Tags: angular, spring-boot, spring-security, null, header

I have 2 applications:

```
localhost:4200 <- angular2 app
localhost:8080 <- spring boot app with security
```

In my a2 auth.service I try to login like this:

```
const customHeaders = new Headers({
        'socialmedia-auth-token': 'ABCDEFGJ'
});
//...
      return this.http.post(loginpoint, JSON.stringify(worker), new RequestOptions({ headers: customHeaders, withCredentials: true }))
        .toPromise()
        .then(result => console.log(result))
        .catch(this.errorHandler);
```

My springboot cors filter:

```
@Component
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CORSFilter implements Filter {

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(CORSFilter.class);

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    
    
    log.info("####### CORS FILTER ###########");

    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;

    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", request.getHeader("Origin"));
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Expose-Headers", "socialmedia-auth-token");
    response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Content-Type, Accept, X-Requested-With, remember-me, socialmedia-auth-token");

    chain.doFilter(req, res);
}
```

And my AuthTokenFilter:

```
public class AuthTokenFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

private static final String TOKEN_HEADER = "socialmedia-auth-token";

private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(AuthTokenFilter.class);

@Override
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain filter)
        throws IOException, ServletException {

    HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
    String authToken = httpRequest.getHeader(TOKEN_HEADER);
    
    log.info("####### AuthTokenFilter: " + authToken + " ###########");
```

The problem is that **authToken** is always null.
I've tried to send request from rest-client extension for google-chrome browser and it works (i just add to **headers from** a single header: socialmedia-auth-token : asdfghhj). I was able to receive asdfghhj in my AuthTokenFilter.

Google Chrome network:[There is no socialmedia-auth-token parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyC18.png)

Can you help me ? I don't know what is wrong with this code.

## Solution

Thank you **chaoluo**. In CORSFilter I changed

```
chain.doFilter
```

to

```
if(!request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) {
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
}
```

and it works. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should return `200` immediately with those headers when the request is preflight request (`Option` method) in your `CORS` filter. More see [here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/) (not-so-simple requests).

```
if (request.getHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin") != null && "OPTIONS".equals(request.getMethod())) {
    // CORS "pre-flight" request
    return ;
}
```

Comment: Thank you ! It works like a charm. I've just edited my main post and add your solution.